# preimage of submanifold is submanifold under submersion

Tags: differential-geometry

What I tried: let $f:M\to N$ be a submersion, $S$ be a submanifold in $N$. Since by regular value theorem, for $q\in N$, $f^
{-1}(q)$ is a submanifold. Then $f^{-1}(S)$ is union of disjoint submanifolds, so $f^{-1}(S)$ is a submanifold.

I think the above proof is wrong, since it didn't use the condition $S$ is a submanifold in $N$. But I don't know where it is wrong.

Edited: Since the above proof is wrong, I was just wondering I haven't learned anything about transversality theorem, then how should I prove the title using regular value theorem?

Comment: why is a disjoint union of submanifolds a submanifold?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think that similar as union of disjoint manifolds is manifolds?

Comment: Let $X$ be the $x$-axis, let $Y_+$ be the positive $y$-axis ($\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2\,:\, x=0,y>0\}$). These are both embedded 1-dimensional submanifolds of $\Bbb{R}^2$. They are also disjoint. But their union is not a submanifold of $\Bbb{R}^2$. What you're probably thinking of is taking two manifolds $M_1,M_2$, and taking the disjoint union $M=M_1\sqcup M_2$, equipped with the disjoint union topology and corresponding smooth structure. But here we're talking about embedded submanifolds, so you're not free to mess around with the structures as you wish.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh, I see, thank you very much! I was just wondering I haven't learned anything about transversality theorem, then how should I prove the title using regular value theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about this question is that it automatically leads you to the definition of transversality. Fix a point $a\in f^{-1}(S)$, and consider the point $b:=f(a)\in S$. Since $S$ is a submanifold of $N$, there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $b$ in $N$ and a submersion $\pi:V\to \Bbb{R}^{\dim N - \dim S}$ such that $V\cap S=\pi^{-1}(\{0\})$. This is just saying submanifolds are locally level sets of submersions. Now, consider the restricted map $\pi\circ f: f^{-1}(V)\to \Bbb{R}^{\dim N - \dim S}$.

- What is the $0$ level set of the restricted map $\pi\circ f$?
- Is $0$ a regular value for $\pi\circ f$?
- Bonus: rewrite an equivalent condition for $0$ being a regular value for $\pi\circ f$ in terms of only $f$ and the submanifold $S$. If you do this successfully, you'll be led to the definition of transversality.

Comment: Thanks again!!! For (1) I think 0 level set is $f^{-1}(V)\cap f^{-1}(S)$. For (2) I think 0 should be a regular value, but I am not sure how to prove it? Then $f^{-1}(V)\cap f^{-1}(S)$ is a submanifold of M, but I am not sure how to conclude preimage of S is a submanifold from here?

Comment: @diiiiiklllllll What kind of map is $f$? What kind of map is $\pi$? So, what kind of map is $\pi\circ f$? Lastly, being a submanifold is a local condition (about every point, there is an open neighborhood such that blablabla... now look again at what this argument shows)

Comment: I think since both $\pi$ and $f$ are submersion, and composition of submersions is submersion then $\pi\circ f$ is a submersion, so need not to show that at $0$, $\pi\circ f$ has full rank? And I am not sure why $\pi$ is submersion? And to be a submanifold of M, need to find a chart $(U \phi ) $ of M, s.t. $\phi(U\cap \mathbb{R}^k)=\phi(U)\cap \mathbb{R}^k$, I just can not see why $f^{-1}(V)\cap f^{-1}(S)$ is a submanifold suggests such a chart?

Comment: @diiiiiklllllll $\pi\circ f$ being a submersion by definition means at each point it has full rank. $\pi$ is a submersion because I chose it to be (and I can do this because $S$ is a submanifold... review the equivalent ways of describing submanifolds). Lastly, I showed for every $a\in f^{-1}(S)$, there is an open set $U$ (namely $f^{-1}(V)$) such that $U\cap f^{-1}(S)$ is the zero level set of a submersion ($\pi\circ f$). This is equivalent to $f^{-1}(S)$ being a submanifold. You should review the equivalent ways of describing submanifolds.

Comment: Thanks, I just start learning differential geometry, and I haven't seen any equivalent definitions of submanifold, and don't understand why S is submanifold suggests such $\pi$ exists. Maybe need more time to think about that.

Comment: Specifically, I'm referring to the following: *"Let $N$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold, and $S\subset N$. Then, $S$ is a smooth $k$-dimensional embedded submanifold of $N$ if and only if for each point $p\in S$, there is an open set $U\subset N$ about $p$ and a smooth submersion $\pi:U\to\Bbb{R}^{n-k}$ such that $U\cap S=\pi^{-1}(\{0\})$"*. The implication $\implies$ follows immediately from the slice-chart definition you quoted; just take $\pi=(\phi^{k+1},\dots, \phi^{k+n})$. For the converse, you use the regular value theorem to generate the slice charts.

Comment: ^ sorry I meant $\pi=(\phi^{k+1},\dots, \phi^n)$, not $\phi^{k+n}$, i.e $\pi$ is just the last $n-k$ component functions of $\phi$.